# Unable to add sub categories in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Iam working on wordpress categories and having issue in creating sub categories. I am able to create and view main category but not the sub category. Please have a look at image below to understand visually.

In this image below iam unable to edit "Women" text under the "Fashion" category, also  need to add another sub category below the "New Arrivals".

[image]

So in this image below Iam able to see the main category like **Fashion** highlited as green and also i can create it without any issue but when i try to add the sub category i see column and banner text rather then **women** or **New Arrivals** adding options. Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image]